# Question for pointer and array and cast(unsigned short)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a[10]={0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};
    unsigned short *p;
    p=(unsigned short *)&a[0];
    *p=1024;
    printf("%d",a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Why answer is 4??
Isn't 1024 entered in array a[0] and a[1] remains?
Why does it affect up to a[1]?

Comment: it's undefined behavior. C forbids accessing `char` via `short`

Comment: The result depends on whether the CPU is big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: The posted code [violates strict aliasing and invokes undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).  It can also invoke undefined behavior [if any alignment restrictions are not met](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7).  Merely creating the pointer is enough to invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

i tested my  self and ,if  you test the  value  of a[0] you will see it  never  change the  pointer is  changing the value  of  a[1] but the  @ in p is the @ of a[0]. interesting behavior
and the  answer is that using  char, for  char max value is 125 if i m not wrong so if  you providing a huge value  will overwrite  the next  value and this is interring

Comment: Signed char max is 127. Unsigned char max is 255.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasoning on a big endian system (most significant byte stored at the smallest address).

```
char a[10]={0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};
```

In binary, your array initially looks like that in your memory :
**0000.0000 0000.0001** 0000.0000 0000.0001 0000.0000 0000.0001  0000.0000 0000.0001 0000.0000 0000.0000

A char only takes a byte in memory.
That means, from right to left, the first **0000.0000** is a[0], then **0000.0001** is a[1], etc.

```
unsigned short *p;
  p=(unsigned short *)&a[0];
  *p=1024;
```

You assigned to p the address of the array. Then you dereferenced it and put in the address stored by p an unsigned short equal to 1024. In binary, 1024 looks like :
0000.0100.0000.0000
An unsigned short takes two bytes in memory.

So,this is what your array becomes after your modification :
**0000.0100.0000.0000** 0000.0000 0000.0001 0000.0000 0000.0001  0000.0000 0000.0001 0000.0000 0000.0000

==> What happened is, since you treated your p as a pointer to an unsigned int, you changed the first 2 bytes instead of just the first one (if it was a char). Then, when you want to access your data via your char array, it will be treated as a char, byte by byte. Then, **0000.0100** which is 4 in decimal is a[0] and **0000.0000** which is 0 in decimal is a[1].

We can deduce that your system is little endian since you instead got 4 for a[1] and 0 for a[0] (I'll let you find more explanations about endianness on google)